# How can I download a huge folder from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, linux

I have a folder shared with me on Google Drive that is much larger than 2 GB. When I try to download it Drive zips the folder but stops when the file size of the zip archive is larger than 2GB.

How can I download this huge folder from Google Drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the open source command-line tool [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) to sync the whole folder to your local hard disk recursively, downloading the contained files recursively instead of in one huge ZIP archive.

Use a command like this:

```
drive pull "Google Drive Folder Name to Download"
```

This will download only changes and new files, so a one-way sync from remote to local. It will ask for confirmation after presenting what would change.

Google Apps files (Google Docs, Google Sheets etc.) will be included only as `*.desktop` files with links to their online versions, since their native format is not accessible. However, you can also tell the command to include exported versions of Google Apps files (which it will do whenever detecting a new or changed Google Apps file):

```
drive pull -export=docx,xlsx,pptx,svg "Folder Name"
```

For more information, see `drive help pull`.

Answer (score 9):

Use [Google Takeout](http://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout).

In the archives, select Google Drive and select the folder you intend to download. If the folder size is greater than 2GB, it gives you the content in different zip files and send email confirmation, so that you can download

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rclone` utility. Install via `apt install rclone`.

Syntax:

```
rclone copy --drive-root-folder-id 1-shared-id-XXX-YYYY gdrive: localdir
```

where `gdrive` is the name of your remote that you've configured.

Check the configuration steps at https://rclone.org/drive/.

GitHub project: https://github.com/rclone/rclone.

Answer (score 0):

I found that [JDownloader 2](https://jdownloader.org/home/index?s=lng_en) does the job perfectly if you want to download a large folder from Google Drive (eg. 20 GB) and don't need to recreate all the original directories.

Just use the function **"capture links"** after pasting the shareable link of your Drive folder.  Then, select all the links JDownloader finds, and hit "download". The result is perfect.

---

> **From the [JDownloader Website](https://jdownloader.org/home/index?s=lng_en):**
>  *JDownloader is a free, open-source download management tool with a huge community that makes downloading as easy and fast as it should be. Users can start, stop or pause downloads, set bandwith limitations, auto-extract archives and much more. It's an easy-to-extend framework that can save hours of your valuable time every day*